# iOS 7 Safari: jwplayer not sending cookie to load m3u8 file (encrypted hls stream)

Tags: ios7, video-streaming, mobile-safari, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

My setup is as follows

1. Webapp hosted at domain A.
2. HLS videos hosted at domain B (.m3u8, .ts and .key files)
3. After loading wbeapp, I create cookie for domain B by loading iframe of domain B (empty iframe)
4. Try to play video using jwplayer which takes path of m3u8 file hosted at domain B.
5. In server B I use cookie to verify if request is authentic and server content.

Everything works perfectly fine on all browsers but on iOS 7 safari, domain cookie is not being sent to domain B along with m3u8 file. I have checked safari settings to never block cookie.

Does anyone know why I am not getting cookie? Am I missing any setting or something? Please let me know for any clarification.

Thank you so much

EDIT
It is not the issue with JWPlayer but iOS 7 device. (Please refer to comments)
For now I made work around to create session in first call when serving m3u8 file. This session is being passed to subsequent requests.

Comment: Do you have a link or an example that you can provide for debugging purposes?

Comment: https://vplayer.mindtickle.com/cfvideo2.php This works in all firefox, chrome, iOS 6 safari, but not in iOS 7 safari. Please note its https url. http may not work.

Comment: What happens if you put your stream (https://vplayer.mindtickle.com/cfvideo2.php/1392701974AllAboardNewHireOnboardingGamificationSaaSProductfromMindTickle.mp4/playlist.m3u8), into a <video> tag? Does it have issues on iOS7 Safari then?

Comment: Updated the link. Tried to put stream in video tag but it didn't work anywhere. am I missing something? What is correct way to put it?

Comment: If there is an issue with your m3u8 stream in a <video> tag on iOS, then there is an issue with the stream itself and it is not a JW Player issue.

Comment: Updated with video tag. Same behavior. Works in everywhere except iOS 7.

Comment: Then it is an issue with your stream, since when using a video tag alone, you are no longer using the JW Player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, Safari decided to ignore the third party cookie, so you cannot set the cookie from your B site with the iframe where your user is trying to access A site.